# Fox News comment on Romney--"self abjination?"

Tags: word-choice, orthography

Watching the discussion led by Dana Perino after the GOP debate this evening, Perino asked if "humility" was a good thing.

Another commentator remarked, "humility yes, self-abjination no." (The spelling is a guess.)

Perino said, "abjination?  I don't know that word."  Someone else said "must be one of those Harvard words."  The commentator said, "it means self deprecating."

So what is the word?  I tried Googling some variants, but came up dry.

Comment: "Self-abjuration" maybe?

Comment: I think it's a malopropism formed from *self-abjuration* and *self-abnegation*. Rubbish "word", IMHO.

Comment: Given that this was fox news, it's not clear if the commentators knew what they were talking about

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Self-abnegation would be my guess as to what was meant.

As a noun, the word self-abnegation is **[defined by dictionary.com as](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/self-abnegation)**

> the denial of one's own interests in favour of the interests of others

Some synonyms from **[The Visual Thesarus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/self-abnegation?posFilter=noun)** for self-abnegation are

- humility
- self-denial
- abjuration
- self-deprecation

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought the spelling was *self-abdignation* suggesting denying your own dignity.

Google suggests that the use of *abdignation* or *self-abdignation* is extremely rare.  I suppose that people might coin them by modelling words like *abnegation*, *abjuration*, *abdication* and *indignation*.